# CodeIgniter CSS will not link to html

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I can't figure out why my css will not link to the html file. I've tried examples online as shown in the code segments, but neither options work. The html page definitely shows as the text 'root-container' is present when I load the localhost folder in the browser. Any help would be great!

Trying to add 'application' before the link does not seem to make a difference either. E.g. 'application/assets/style/navigation.css'.

Also, helper and url have been added to the autoload config file.

**BASE URL**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/';
```

**PROJECT STRUCTURE**

Omitting root folder. Assume root folder name is 'mysite'. So mysite -> application -> ...

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="<?php echo 
base_url('application/assets/style/navigation.css')?>">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo 
base_url(); ?>assets/style/navigation.css">

  <?php echo link_tag('assets/style/navigation.css'); ?>

</head>

<body>
  <div class = "root-container">
    root-container


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.root-container {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  background-color: black;
  color: red;

}

.root-container p {
  color:red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**Adding requested image**

[image]

**result**
Text should be red and have line scored through it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okey , you move assets file to your main directory and edit application/assets/style/navigation.css to assets/style/navigation.css

Comment: pls paste last css link?

Comment: application/assets/style/navigation.css

Comment: open site and press ctrl + u and take screanshot and share

Comment: I've already added the helper to autoload. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: can I connect remotely and understand the problem?
like teamviewer

Comment: Sorry I cannot do that. Thanks for the help though

Comment: what exactly is the problem? the CSS path looks correct

Comment: The css styling doesn't apply to the html for some reason. I don't understand the problem either. I thought it was a problem with the paths that I'm trying to link but I've tried a lot of different ways and none seem to be working :\

Comment: click link if you see your css content path is corret if dont open link path wrong

Comment: okey , you move assets file to your main directory and edit application/assets/style/navigation.css to assets/style/navigation.css

Comment: but application directory is blocket
``
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
``

Comment: Your suggestion to move the folder worked, thanks very much!

Comment: Add the answer to your post and I will mark it correct